# Test if number from range <0,infinity)

Tags: bash, exit, test

I have a problem

```
If [[ * ]]
then
continue

else
exit 1
fi
```

I want to test that the argument to my switch (for example `-d 3`) is a valid positive decimal integer number (a sequence of one or more of any of the ASCII characters from `0` to `9`). After `-d` there can be only be a number `[0,infinity)`. Everything else is bad. I do not know what to put instead of `*`.

Can you help me ? 
Argument after `-d` is at `$2` position.

Comment: Can you safely assume that the value will always be a number? What if a user enters letters?

Comment: Are 0x123, 1.23e20, 4+4, 2#1111, 0123, 0888, -0.00, 1.23, .123 acceptable numbers?

Comment: acceptable are only 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....infinity. only integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any Bourne-like shell (that is, going back as far back as the 70s):

```
case $2 in
  "" | *[!0-9]*) echo >&2 not OK; exit 1;;
  *) echo OK;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

From your question and comments, you need `$2` to be a non-negative integer:

```
if [[ "$2" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
...
```

Note also that `if` is written with a lowercase `i`.

If your version of Bash doesn't support regular expressions (<3.x), you can use `grep` to do the heavy lifting for you:

```
if printf "%s\n" "$2" | grep -qE '^[0-9]+$'
then
...
```

but see [Stephane's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102108/test-if-number-from-range-0-infinity/102109?noredirect=1#comment155899_102109) for a possible caveat of this approach.

Comment: +1 but that of course assumes that `$2` is a number.

Comment: @terdon You're right, of course. I updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: this dont work for me

Comment: @xpukm Please elaborate. What happens and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @xpukm JosephR is assuming that you run your script like this: `script.sh -d 3` in which case `$2` will be whatever you give after `-d`. How are you testing it?

Comment: script look like this 
`/script.csh -d <something> <path to directories>`
tester is changing the value of `something` for example integer, negative integer, blank space, string, special characters and the only thing when it should continue should be when `something` is integer from <0,infinity).
Some test run ok with this solution some not.

Comment: @xpukm and what behavior do you get with the above answer?

Comment: in one test where `something` was not a number but some string or what the script didnt exit but continue

Comment: @xpukm is this bash or csh? Anyway, please post your actual script if you want this kind of detail. This answer is not causing the script to exit, you did not say you wanted that. It has given you a way of testing whether something is a positive number. How you handle the result of that test is up to you.

Comment: i tried `"$2" =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$` and it says  conditional binary operator expected

Comment: it is bash2 and in my question there is written if it is number then continue else exit.

Comment: @xpukm Yes, it is written, sorry. I asked about bash  because your script has a .csh extension. You get that error if you don't use two `[[`, make sure you copy directly from the answer, it should be `if [[ ... ]]` note the double `[[` and `]]` and the spaces, all are important.

Comment: i copied it and i know there must be blank spaces and double [[ but it is not working i dont know why now i am trying something else

Comment: @xpukm if by "bash2" you mean Bash version 2, then regex matching with `=~` is [not supported](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html) for your version of Bash.

Comment: yes it is bash version 2. I must find solution it drives me crazy. it mus continue only and only if after -d is number from 0 to infinity everything else is exit.

Comment: @xpukm See the updated answer.

Comment: Your `grep` one would say that `$'123\nblah'` is a valid number. See also `expr`'s `:` operator.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: what is wrong with that grep can you edit it please ?

Comment: that grep you write worked for me without that `expr` even if i put after `-d dasf54654dsfa` it worked so where is problem??

Comment: Note that  it would say that `.123`, `-0`, `123.` are not valid, and that `0888` is valid (though some would complain that it's invalid octal)

Comment: @xpukm I don't know what the problem is. Meanwhile, there are also Stephane's caveats to deal with and you should update your question to tell us which of the number formats Stephane suggests are valid for your use case and which are not.

Comment: this number is argument for find -maxdepth $2

Comment: so it must be integer 0,1,2,3,4,5....infinity

Comment: @xpukm In that case, 0 should be excluded, no?

Comment: in case it is 0 i do not know i tried just write find -maxdepth 0 and it output one directory so i think 0 is okay for maxdepth

Comment: can you edit grep above to work with integer only because it work even with 0.8 and so on

Comment: @xpukm That should do it. But note [Stephane's comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102108/test-if-number-from-range-0-infinity/102109?noredirect=1#comment155899_102109) about a caveat.

Comment: did you edit that ? because it says you did but nothing changed. it still works with 0.8 and so on

Comment: @xpukm Sorry, I had only edited the Bash one.

Comment: thank you i will run it through tester and maybe it will work

Comment: Finally working thank you :) every test was ok :)